# MVVM-C with RxSwift: '[weak self]' in closure

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I'm working on an iOS project with RxSwift and I use the MVVM with coordinators pattern.

Here my implementation:

*ViewModel:*

```
// MARK: - Private

private let showNextViewSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()

// MARK: - Inputs

var showNextView: AnyObserver<Void> {
    return showNextViewSubject.asObserver()
}

// MARK: - Outputs

var didShowNextView: Observable<Void> {
    return showNextViewSubject.asObservable()
}
```

*ViewController:*

```
private func bindButton() {
    _ = button.rx.tap
        .bind(to: viewModel.showNextView)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

*Coordinator:*

```
self.viewModel.didShowNextView
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.showNextView()
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

My problem is with the `[weak self] _` in the coordinator: when I add it, `self?.showNextView()` is never called, but this works well when I remove it.

Do you know why?

Thanks,
Romain

Answer (score 3):

When you get rid of `[weak self]` the block creates a strong reference to `self` so that it's not deallocated when any other code is done using it. By making the reference weak `self` is free to be deallocated which is probably happening. This means there is no other object with a strong reference to `self` so it is nil and the call won't be made.  Getting rid of it could create a retain cycle so you'll want to be careful of that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, I don't understand why, but I have tried to add a print in my closure to listen the subscribe: with `[weak self] _`, nothing happen and without, it works…

Comment: Seems like you have other dependency problems.

Comment: If it's not executed, it's probably because your coordinator is deallocated before the event fire. I guess there is no strong reference to your previous coordinator. You can check that by adding `print(...)` in the `deinit`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not add [weak self], completion block will retain self and this is not a best way to use blocks. 
You should have a reference (retain) to your coordinator and it should be released when you are done with it.

[Memory management in RxSwift](http://adamborek.com/memory-managment-rxswift/)

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 4.2 you could safely rewrite the snippet as:

```
self.viewModel.didShowNextView
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return } 
        self.showNextView()
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This pattern is generally recommended over using `self?`.

Comment: There is 0 difference between the code you wrote above and just using `self?`

Answer (score 1):

just keep a reference to a this coordinator in his parent coordinator like this

```
private var childCoordinators = [CoordinatorType]()
```

so it won't be deallocated